# Problem refreshing graph in kivy (python)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, kivy

I've been trying to create sort of a gauge & needle widget to use in an app. Ideally I would use it to continuously show the evolution of a certain variable while the app runs.

I've managed to make it work in windows by using the latest kivy and kivy-garden, and matplotlib version 3.5.0. I'm not sure about the versions in between, but with the latest version of matplotlib the app wouldn't run, raising an error with FigureCanvasKivyAgg.

The class as it is written has a method that can be used to update the position of the needle with another value.
The "app" has two buttons. "One" just generates a random number and updates the position of the needle. "Loop" does the same, but in a loop a certain number of times.

The problem that I'm having is that the loop function doesn't continuously change the position of the needle. I can see it working because the values are being printed onto the console, but the program freezes while the loop is running and just shows the last value generated by the loop.

Any way I can fix that?

Here is the code. First the class for the widget, then de test app.

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('module://kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivy')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi
matplotlib.use('svg')

####################################################################################################
###                                          Dial class                                          ###
####################################################################################################

class Dial(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Dial, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(projection="polar")

        self.arco_total = pi
        self.segs = [
            0,
            pi*0.1,
            pi*0.2,
            pi*0.3,
            pi*0.4,
            pi*0.5,
            pi*0.6,
            pi*0.7,
            pi*0.8,
            pi*0.9,
            pi
            ] 

        self.labels=[1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0]

        self.ax.bar(
            x=self.segs[:-1],
            width=self.arco_total/(len(self.segs)-1),
            height=0.05,
            bottom=2,
            color="black",
            align="edge",
            linewidth=0.5,
            edgecolor="white")

        for loc, valor in zip(self.segs, self.labels):
            self.ax.annotate(valor, xy=(loc, 2.05), ha="right" if valor<0.5 else "left")

        self.value=0
        self.needle = self.ax.annotate(
            " ",
            xytext=(0,0),
            xy=((pi*(1-self.value)), 2.0),
            arrowprops=dict(
                arrowstyle="wedge",
                color="black",
                # mutation_scale=25,
                shrinkA=0
            ),
            bbox=dict(
                boxstyle="circle",
                facecolor="black",
                linewidth=1.0
            ),
            fontsize=15,
            color="black",
            ha="center"
        )

        self.ax.set_axis_off()
        self.ax.set_thetamin(0)
        self.ax.set_thetamax(180)
        self.ax.figure.tight_layout()

        self.graph = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(self.fig)

        self.add_widget(self.graph)

    
    def actualizar_valor(self, valor):
        self.needle.xy=[pi*(1-valor), 2.0]
        self.graph.draw()


####################################################################################################
###                                           Test app                                           ###
####################################################################################################

import kivy
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import random
import time as tm



class main(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(main, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.dial = Dial()

        self.button1 = Button(
            text="One",
        )
        self.button1.bind(on_press = self.one)

        self.button2 = Button(
            text="Loop",
        )
        self.button2.bind(on_press = self.loop)

        #Distribución de los widgets
        self.layout_1 = BoxLayout(size_hint=(1, 0.8))
        self.layout_1.add_widget(self.dial)
        self.layout_2 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal', size_hint=(1, 0.2))
        self.layout_2.add_widget(self.button1)
        self.layout_2.add_widget(self.button2)
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.layout.add_widget(self.layout_1)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.layout_2)

    def build(self):
        return self.layout
    
    def one(self, evento):
        # for i in range(5):
        val = random.uniform(0,1)
        # print(val)
        self.dial.actualizar_valor(val)
        # tm.sleep(1.0)
    

    def loop(self, evento):
        for i in range(5):
            val = random.uniform(0,1)
            print(val)
            self.dial.actualizar_valor(val)
            tm.sleep(0.5)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main().run()
```

Any help/suggestions will be welcome. Thanks

I've had a similar problem with tkinter, and I managed to solve it by putting the "update function" on a separate thread. I couldn't make it work with kivy though.

Comment: thanks for posting a running example.  For those that have not used garden, you have to install kivy garden and also at the terminal you have to enter "garden install matplotlib" to install that matplotlib feature

Answer (score 0):

at the top of your code, import this object.

```
from kivy.clock import mainthread
```

replace your loop function with this code.

```
@mainthread
def update_dial(self, the_value):
    self.dial.actualizar_valor(the_value)

def run_thread(self):
    for i in range(5):
        val = random.uniform(0, 1)
        print(val)
        self.update_dial(val)
        tm.sleep(0.5)

def loop(self, evento):
    print(evento)
    threading.Thread(target=self.run_thread, daemon=True).start()
```

You need to free the main thread to run Kivy things.  I'm sorry I don't have a better explanation than that, I just know the modification makes the needle move around and frees the gui directly after the button press.

The @mainthread decorator is required because Kivy has to be in the main thread to do graphics updates.